# Trying to check user input against csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, validation, input, robobrowser

I'm trying to create a script that will take a zip code from a user and then check it against a csv file to validate that it is a real zip code. I then use robobrowser to pull some weather data from the web. I'm having trouble comparing the the user input to my csv file.  I've tried a couple different things I saw on here but can't seem to figure it out.  If the zip code is correct it should be passed on, if not the user should be asked for the zip code again. I'm looking for anyway to check the input against csv file. It's probably an easy fix I just cant seem to figure it out. The csv file has a bunch of columns but I only really want to deal with the first one which is called zip. Thanks in advance!

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
import csv


def location():
    global zipcode

    zipcode = input('Please enter your five digit zip code:\n')

    with open(r'C:\Users\Josh\PycharmProjects\Scripting_fund\zip.csv') as zipcodefile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(zipcodefile)
    for row in reader:
        if row['zip'] == zipcode :
            lookup()
        else:
            location()
```

Comment: A few things: 1) the code in `location()` isn't properly indented, don't know what it does? 2) What does the csv data look like that you are using `startswith`? Would `==` not work in this situation?

Comment: @Sparrow1029 Sorry the indentation was just my mistake when putting the code on here. location() should receive a zip code and then compare that zip code with the csv file. The csv file has 15 columns but the only one I want to work with at the moment is called "zip". That column has every US zip code so its fairly long. I downloaded it from unitedstateszipcodes.org.There is really no reason to be using startswith so i changed my code to reflect that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample script that might work for what you are trying to do:

```py
import csv

ZIPCODES = []


def valid(zipcode):
    return zipcode in ZIPCODES


def location():
    while True:
        zipcode = input('Please enter your five digit zip code:\n')
        if valid(zipcode):
            return zipcode
        else:
            print("That's not a valid zipcode.")
            continue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(r'C:\Users\Josh\PycharmProjects\Scripting_fund\zip.csv') as zipcodefile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(zipcodefile)
        ZIPCODES = [row['zip'] for row in reader]

    user_zipcode = location()
```

It's generally best to avoid the `global` statement, but if you do use it, you would need `zipcode` to be initiated *outside* the function you are defining it in... you may have done that and just not included it in your question.